# How do I write Json path expression for my payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-maps

Here is my payload and I need to extract short_name of country & state

$.results[0].address_components[what goes here to extract].short_name

The objects are not consistent.

```
{
           "long_name": "San Francisco County",
           "short_name": "San Francisco County",
           "types": [
              "administrative_area_level_2",
              "political"
           ]
        },
        {
           "long_name": "California",
           "short_name": "CA",
           "types": [
              "administrative_area_level_1",
              "political"
           ]
        },
        {
           "long_name": "United States",
           "short_name": "US",
           "types": [
              "country",
              "political"
           ]
        },
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `what goes here to extract` ... 0, or 1, or 2 ... up to `n` where `n` is `$.results[0].address_components.length - 1` - because if what you're showing is `$.results[0].address_components` it's an *Array*

Comment: I cannot use absolute values (0,1,2,.....n) since I wouldn't know which object will have required info. The thing that goes in there should be a condition that checks what type of object it is.

Comment: huh? you'll have to iterate and find the required object then